# Unable to login domain joined server getting permission denied error

Tags: server, ssh, connection

Getting error as "Permission denied, please try again" for domain user login in domain joined server.

got this log in /var/log/auth.log:

```
Dec  1 11:03:00 Host sshd[61122]: Invalid user ad.empid from 127.0.0.1 port 41358
Dec  1 11:03:07 Host sshd[61122]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec  1 11:03:07 Host sshd[61122]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=127.0.0.1
Dec  1 11:03:07 Host sshd[61122]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=127.0.0.1 user=ad.empid
Dec  1 11:03:07 Host sshd[61122]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user ad.empid: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
Dec  1 11:03:09 Host sshd[61122]: Failed password for invalid user ad.empid from 127.0.0.1 port 41358 ssh2
Dec  1 11:03:15 Host sshd[61122]: Connection closed by invalid user ad.empid 127.0.0.1 port 41358 [preauth]
Dec  1 11:03:32 Host realmd[61114]: quitting realmd service after timeout
Dec  1 11:03:32 Host realmd[61114]: stopping service
Dec  1 11:13:59 Host sshd[61152]: warning: /etc/hosts.deny, line 18: host name/address mismatch: Server_IP != Host
Dec  1 11:14:03 Host sshd[61152]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=Server_IP  user=ad.empid
Dec  1 11:14:46 Host sshd[61152]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=Server_IP user=ad.empid
Dec  1 11:14:46 Host sshd[61152]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user ad.empid: 4 (System error)
Dec  1 11:14:48 Host sshd[61152]: Failed password for ad.empid from Server_IP port 33714 ssh2
Dec  1 11:15:59 Host sshd[61152]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for Server_IP port 33714
```